# Vector bundles and their extensions

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E'$ and $E''$ be a vector bundles over a complex manifold $X$. An extension of $E''$ by $E'$ is a an exact sequence of vector bundles

$$
0 \longrightarrow E'\longrightarrow E \longrightarrow E'' \longrightarrow 0.
$$

Two extensions of $E''$ by $E'$ are equivalent if we have an isomorphism of exact sequences

$$
0 \longrightarrow E'\longrightarrow E_1 \longrightarrow E'' \longrightarrow 0,
$$

and

$$
0 \longrightarrow E'\longrightarrow E_2 \longrightarrow E'' \longrightarrow 0.
$$

I'm looking for a proof for the following proposition

> The equivalence classes of extensions of $E''$ by $E'$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $H^1(X,\operatorname{Hom}(E'',E'))$, the trivial extension corresponding to the zero element.

I have not seen these extensions defined in pretty much any book on complex/differential geometry and cannot find a proof for the above result. If someone here has knowledge on where these things are discussed I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of definitions, you can find definitions in any book on homological algebra, (e.g. Weibel's book) though you probably need to be comfortable with what a sheaf is and how to associate a locally free sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules to a vector bundle. In terms of computation, Cech cocycles are probably the most concrete way to understand what an element of either side "looks like".

Note that if $0 \to E' \to E \to E''\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of vector bundles, then if $\mathcal E,\mathcal E',\mathcal E''$ are the corresponding locally free sheaves of sections of $E$,$E'$ and $E''$ respectively, then $0 \to \mathcal E' \to \mathcal E \to \mathcal E'' \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of sheaves. In this way, short exact sequences of vector bundles exactly correspond to short exact sequences of the associated locally-free sheaves.

For any two vector bundles $E'$ and $E''$ you can use the (multi)-linear algebra constructions on each fibre to form vector bundles $E'\otimes E''$ and $\mathcal Hom(E',E'')$, where I use the calligraphic $\mathcal H$ to distinguish the vector bundle from the vector space of maps from the bundle $E'$ to $E''$. These operations are called the "internal" Hom and tensor product for (the category of) vector bundles on $X$.

In contrast, $\text{Hom}(E',E'')$ is the vector space of maps of bundles. In the complex analytic setting, for example, these are holomorphic maps from the total space of $E'$ to the total space of $E''$ which are the identity when restricted to $X$ (viewed as the zero section) and which are linear on the fibres of the bundles.  The relationship between the two is straight-forward though -- $\mathrm{Hom}(E',E'')$ is just the space of global sections $\Gamma(X,\mathcal Hom(E',E''))$  of the $\mathcal Hom$-vector bundle (or $\mathcal Hom$-sheaf, since this is defined by requiring its sections over an open set to be space of sections to the bundle map). Similar considerations show that there is a natural identification $\mathbb C_X\otimes E' = E'$.

Now if $\mathbb C_X$ denotes the trivial rank 1 vector bundle on $X$ (that is, $\mathbb C_X = X\times \mathbb C$, then $\phi\in \text{Hom}(\mathbb C_X, E')$ is completely determined by its value on $1 \in \mathbb C$, and $\phi(1)$ is a global section of $E'$, so there is a natural identification $\text{Hom}(\mathbb C_X,E') = \Gamma(X,E')$.

Using this and an "internal" version of tensor-Hom adjunction, which is standard (but perhaps not quite obvious) you can establish the identity relating $\text{Ext}^1$ to $H^1$ of the internal Hom:
The identification you ask about can be established as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Ext}^1(E'',E')& =\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb C_X \otimes E'',E') = \text{Ext}^1(\mathbb C_X, \mathcal Hom(E'',E'))\\
& \text{R}\mathcal Hom^1(\mathbb C_X,\mathcal Hom(E'',E')) = \text{R}\Gamma^1(X,\mathcal Hom(E'',E')) \\
&=H^1(X,\mathcal Hom(E'',E')).
\end{split}
$$
as required. Here you can do the calculation using the vector bundle or their associated locally-free sheaves, because it can be checked that the vector bundle $\mathcal Hom(E'',E')$ is that associated to the locally-free sheaf $\mathcal Hom(\mathcal E'',\mathcal E')$ (this assertion implicitly includes the assertion that the $\mathcal Hom$-sheaf is locally free!) and similarly for $E''\otimes E'$ and $\mathcal E''\otimes \mathcal E'$.

Comment: So the sequences here should be thought of as exact sequences of sheaves? @krm2233

Comment: I've updated my answer to give some more details about the objects you need to understand. Let me know if that has helped!

Comment: I may be missing something, but should the hom-sheaf now contain $\mathcal E''$ and $\mathcal E'$ instead? @krm2233

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify this. I had a typo before where $E'$ and $E''$ were the wrong way around in the second line of the calculation, but probably more importantly, you can do the calculation with vector bundles or locally free sheaves. If you want to know how to use something like Cech cohomology to compute what the Ext group actually is, however, searching for  resources on "sheaf cohomology" is a better bet than search for "vector bundle cohomology".